# How to open a Ruby file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, ruby

I have a ruby file saved on my desktop as test.rb.
How can I open it with terminal? 
I have already tried to use */home/desktop/test.rb* and what I get in response is *bash: /home/desktop/test.rb: No such file or directory*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ruby` command, which calls the Ruby interpreter on your file:

```
ruby ~/Desktop/test.rb
```

This way you don't need to make your file executable.

(The tilde symbol `~` is a shorthand for the path to your home folder which is `/home/<your-username>`.)

If you still need to make your script executable I hope you remembered to type the shebang line on the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

then run `chmod +x ~/Desktop/test.rb` on the terminal to make `test.rb` executable.

Comment: If this post answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`/home/<username>/` is the path of your home-directory. If you start your Terminal, your Shell starts in your home-directory, you can print that path with the command

```
$ pwd
```

The you need the path of the Desktop-Folder, try it with

```
$ ls
```

Your final command than will probably look like that:

```
~$ ./Desktop/test.rb
```

But you should try a tutorial for the Linux shell, like this one: [LinuxCommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php)

Comment: Thank you, but it says access denied, what can I do?

Comment: The file isn't executable. Try `chmod +x ./Desktop/test.rb` and after that try to execute the file again. If you want to know more try `man chmod` (can be closed by tipping 'q')

Answer (score 0):

Your home directory is `/home/<your username>/`. Your Desktop is `/home/<your username>/Desktop`.

You forgot the `<your username>` part of it.

Comment: That didn't quite work.